# R's Dexp function equivalent in Python

Tags: python, r

Folks,

How can I get equivalent of following R's function in Python

```
x <- dexp(c(1:10), rate=1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python itself does not have many predefined functions, but you can use scipy.stats:
@Terminal:

```
pip install scipy
```

@Python:

```
from scipy.stats import expon

print(expon.pdf(1))
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html

Comment: Works perfect, Thanks!